# SWAGGER, @Configuration doesn't work with SpringFoxConfig

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I work with Spring boot framework, I try to comment on my APIs with Swagger but it doesn't work.
I'm almost sure that the problem is in the SpringFoxConfig configuration class.

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {


    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.techprimers.springboot.swaggerexample"))
                .paths(regex("/rest.*"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metaInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo metaInfo() {

        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "Spring Boot Swagger Example API",
                "Spring Boot Swagger Example API for Youtube",
                "1.0",
                "Terms of Service",
                new Contact("TechPrimers", "https://www.youtube.com/TechPrimers",
                        "techprimerschannel@gmail.com"),
                "Apache License Version 2.0",
                "https://www.apache.org/licesen.html"
        );

        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

in my POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

The program does not work and he shows me this [image: erreur] when I run it with @Configuration but when I remove @Configuration it runs and when I type http://localhost:9080/swagger-ui.html it does not show me anything ( see the figure above) knowing that I want him to show me the information I wrote in the SpringFoxConfig class.

[image: Swagger UI]
Do you have a solution or an explanation for my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line in your SwaggerConfig file.

**apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
.paths(PathSelectors.any())**

for all  controllers methods.

Adding this to your WebSecurityConfiguration class .

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                                   "/configuration/ui",
                                   "/swagger-resources/**",
                                   "/configuration/security",
                                   "/swagger-ui.html",
                                   "/webjars/**");
    }

}
```

Comment: I am still a beginner in Spring,  I don't know and I have never worked with WebSecurityConfiguration. Regarding the replacement of .apis and .paths by RequestHandlerSelectors.any () and PathSelectors.any () it didn't work as well (same problem)

Comment: here are all the imports I used :
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

Comment: Try to do like this - https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-restful-api-documentation-with-swagger    and check if any spring security dependency is there in your pom or not ?

Comment: I did the same thing as him in the tutorial. but my problem is when compiling

Comment: I found the solution of this problem, in my situation it was caused by guava conflict. some dependencies depends on guava 18.0 , however , there is no FluentIterable in guava 18 . so I set execlusions in these dependencies , and add guava 20 as a new dependency.